# how to split a string having more than one separator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains a column which has strings as shown below

```
qwe1
tre1.eyyu
cvbn.poiu.sdfg

- A value could be a single string (qwe1)
- A value could have one delimiter, i.e ".", and characters on both side of it.(tre1.eyyu)
- A value could have two delimiters. (cvbn.poiu.sdfg)
```

code as below

```
p1 = "<path_to_parquet file>"
df_ref_parquet = spark.read.option('header', True).parquet(p1)
table = [x["FILList"] for x in df_LDR_parquet.rdd.collect()]
fil_cd_left = []
for row in table:
    row.split(".")
        fil_cd_left.append(row[0:4])
print(fil_cd_left)
```

I want to create 3 lists out of them.

```
- hence I have written a script that will iterate over the data frame, split it on "." and create a first list that has all values in the default format as shown above.
- Now I have applied python slicing to get extreme left hand side 4 characters before the delimiter ".", and appended it to another list.
```

However, I am not able to create another two list that would hold extreme right hand side characters of the delimiter, and the set of chars those are present in between the 2 delimiters.

Please suggest, Please let me know if I was not able to explain properly. I will try to re-phrase.

Note: I have searched in Stackoverflow for other articles, but they don't seem to relate to my scenario.

Comment: row.split('.') returns a list of the different parts of your string: try a = row.split('.') then print(a) and you'll be able to fix your code from there.

Comment: I didn't know that split() function splits the stings at multiple delimiters as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a three list every time, please pre-define it.

```
for row in table:
    out = ['','', '']
    for index, word in enumerate(row.split('.', maxsplit=2)):
        out[index] = word
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
['qwe1', '', '']
['tre1', 'eyyu', '']
['cvbn', 'poiu', 'sdfg']
```